# DNN 7 Can No Longer Edit Page

Tags: dotnetnuke

One of my DNN 7 sites has lost its ability to edit any of the pages.  It now alway displays the Modules, Edit and Pages menu regardless if admin is logged in or not.  When I try to edit a page, a window appears and then quickly goes away.  There is nothing of use in the event log and I have tried different skins with no luck.  I have another DNN website on the same computer and it works fine.

I have found that I am losing permissions to ToggleUserMode after I recompile a custom module that I'm developing has been installed on a test page and then recompiled in debug mode.

I'm wondering if this can be related to the fact that when I install DNN I blank out the default installation option of creating a dotnetnuke application.  I leave that option blank and create the installation in the root of my website.

P.S I tried the amended module tag suggested on SO without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.  I had originally bound www.example.com to my default website but later created a new site for www.example.com.  Apparently most of the requests were going to my new site, but the request for authorization for page editing was going to my old site which resulted in the 401 error.  I rebooted my computer and disabled my default website and all is well.